# ElasticSearch mongo always 0 hits

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mongo-river

I'm trying to make ElasticSearch run over my Mongodb server, everything looks fine, but every query I do returns me 0 hits. Always.

My installation and configuration log:

1. Installed Mongodb 2.6.4

> Up and running. No problems here. I have like 7000 products inside "products" collection.

.2 Created replica set.

> Confirmed with rs.status() on Mongo shell that it's created and it's
>   the primary replica Changed mongod.conf with resplSet = rs0
>   oplogSize=100

.3. Restarted MongoDB

.4. Initiated the replica set

> On mongo shell rs.initiate(). Everything fine.

.5. Installed ElasticSearch 1.3.2

```
{
  "status": 200,
  "name": "Franz Kafka",
  "version": {
    "number": "1.3.2",
    "build_hash": "dee175dbe2f254f3f26992f5d7591939aaefd12f",
    "build_timestamp": "2014-08-13T14:29:30Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "4.9"
  },
  "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

.6. Installed Mapper plugin

.7. Installed River plugin

.8. Create index

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/indexprueba/products/_meta?pretty=true' -d '{
  "type": "mongodb",
  "mongodb": {
    "db": "test",
    "collection": "products"
  },
  "index": {
    "name": "probando1",
    "type": "products"
  }
}'
```

it returns:

```
{
  "_index": "indexprueba",
  "_type": "products",
  "_id": "_meta",
  "_version": 1,
  "created": true
}
```

--------EDIT---------

8.5 Restore database

I didn't do this. Once I've created the index, I restore my database with mongorestore and this is what I get:

```
connected to: 127.0.0.1:27017
2014-09-08T08:17:17.773+0000 /var/backup/bikebud/products.bson
2014-09-08T08:17:17.773+0000    going into namespace [test.products]
Restoring to test.products without dropping. Restored data will be inserted without raising errors; check your server log
6947 objects found
2014-09-08T08:17:18.043+0000    Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "test.products" }
2014-09-08T08:17:18.456+0000 /var/backup/bikebud/retailers.bson
2014-09-08T08:17:18.457+0000    going into namespace [test.retailers]
Restoring to test.retailers without dropping. Restored data will be inserted without raising errors; check your server log
20 objects found
2014-09-08T08:17:18.457+0000    Creating index: { key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "test.retailers" }
```

So I understand from here that my indexes are created and linked to the database

--------EDIT---------

.9. Create simple query

```
curl -XGET `'http://127.0.0.1:9200/indexprueba/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*'`
```

Always returns:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

----------------EDIT-------------------

After the edit, this is what I get:

```
{
  "took": 14,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "testindex1",
        "_type": "products",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "type": "mongodb",
          "mongodb": {
            "servers": [
              {
                "host": "127.0.0.1",
                "port": 27017
              }
            ],
            "options": {
              "secondary_read_preference": true
            },
            "db": "test",
            "collection": "products"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So now I get hits, but is the index itself. I was expecting to get all products from my database. I start to think I don't understand at all what elasticsearch does. Any clue??

----------------EDIT-------------------

I don't know what I'm missing here. Please, any advice?

----------------EDIT-------------------

It looks like it was a version problem. I have to downgrade ES to 1.2.2 (I'm using 1.3.2).
"Resolved"

Comment: I don't see where you actually load any data into either mongodb or elasticsearch.

Comment: The mongo DB is filled with data already. Like 7000 products. And im indexing the "products" collection there (point 8), so it should work, as i understand. 
But that's the problem, i don't seem to understand, because it wont work...

Comment: What does `curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/indexprueba/_stats'` say? Are there documents in your index?

Comment: And about my index... Yes, i create the index, i use mongorestore and it says that my index is created, so i guees it has the same data i have on my mongodb

Comment: That's what _stats say : {"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":2,"failed":3,"failures":[{"index":"_river","s‌​hard":2,"reason":"BroadcastShardOperationFailedException[[_river][2] ]; nested: ElasticsearchException[io exception while building 'store stats']; nested: NoSuchDirectoryException[directory '/etc/elasticsearch/data/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/_river/2/index' does not exist]; –   

I've created the folders that are missing and now it says: {"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"_all":{"primaries":{"docs":{"count":4,"deleted":0},"store":{"size_i (the result is much much longer)

Comment: I think the problem is in river plugin, because i don't get errors but is always 0 hits, like if i haven't any data on my index.
My cluster health is green and when i do mongorestore it says "index created", so im kinda lost.

Comment: Looking at elasticsearch log i found this:

[2014-09-10 07:40:04,696][INFO ][node                     ] [Nodo1] version[1.3.2], pid[21136], build[dee175d/2014-08-13T14:29:30Z]
[2014-09-10 07:40:04,696][INFO ][node                     ] [Nodo1] initializing ...
[2014-09-10 07:40:04,700][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Nodo1] loaded [], sites []
[2014-09-10 07:40:07,142][WARN ][common.network           ] failed to resolve local host, fallback to loopback
java.net.UnknownHostException: mongo-spain-managed-server: mongo-spain-managed-server: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetA

Comment: I changed my hosts file so now it knows my domain. Now the log says:

node] [Nodo1] initialized

node] [Nodo1] starting ...

transport] [Nodo1] bound_address {local[1]}, publish_address {local[1]}

discovery] [Nodo1] miCluster/-l3SDtGcTQKj9ccl73Y2gA

cluster.service] [Nodo1] new_master 
[Nodo1][-l3SDtGcTQKj9ccl73Y2gA][mongo-spain-managed-server][local[1]]{local=true}, reason: local-disco-initial_connec$
[gateway] [Nodo1] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[http] [Nodo1] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9201]}, publish_address {inet[/172.31.4.98:9201]}
[node] [Nodo1] started

Comment: Ok, now i've seen this error " plugin mongodb-river, failed to invoke custom onModule method" and it looks like i have to downgrade ES to 1.2.2

Comment: was there any resolution eventually ? I am facing the problem with elasticsearch 1.4.2 and mongodb 2.6.6